# How do I stop my puppy from licking her pee from training pads?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training, drinking

My 3 month old shih tzu is licking her pee after she goes on the training pads. How do I stop her from doing this? She has plenty of water and food. Help

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. In order to get the answer you're looking for, could you please include more information about your problem, for example when you started to notice this, etc?